# Disable url rewrite for specific urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?region=$1&city=$2&course=$3&page=$4
RewriteRule ^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)$ index.php?region=$1&city=$2&course=$3
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

If i access

```
templates/firstTemplate/css/style.css
```

It redirects to index.php, so my style.css is not applied, how can i disable url redirection for this specific url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions only get applied to the immediately following rule, which means your second and third rules don't have any of the needed conditions. You need to repeat them for your other two rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?region=$1&city=$2&course=$3&page=$4

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)$ index.php?region=$1&city=$2&course=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: ur amazing i was googling for hours about this cuz my `post ` using ajax is conflicted with rewritten urls so yea this helped me and fixed it, Thank You <3